# Не активна кнопка поиска на панели задач в windows 10 LTSC вообще

Tags: windows, windows-10

- Скачал windows 10 LTSC. И в ней не работает поиск на панели задач от
  слова совсем. Кнопка поиска не подает никаких признаков жизни.
- Все способы из трех поисковиков перепробовал, при чем я не могу, как
  написано на разных форумах, использовать средство устранения
  неполадок, т.к. для поиска его у меня просто почему-то нет.
- В безопасном режиме тоже не активен.
- Параметры индексирования в панели управления (через которые тоже
  чинили поиск) отсутствуют (точнее там просто белый лист в виде
  иконки).
- *sfc /scannow* и/или *dim.exe* не помагают.

**ХОЧУ СДЕЛАТЬ БЕЗ ПЕРЕУСТАНОВКИ СИСТЕМЫ**

В чем может заключаться промбема?
Как ее исправить БЕЗ ПЕРЕУСТАНОВКИ СИСТЕМЫ?

P.S. На хабре мне помочь не смогли ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Comment: Качали с сайта Майкрософт или как обычно?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, как обычно)

Comment: Тогда говорить не о чем. У вас может быть все что угодно

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, например?

Comment: Например, тот кто делал сборку целенаправленно выбросил поддержку поиска для уменьшения размера

Comment: Поддержу @AntonShchyrov, обратись к тому, кто делал сборку. Кто собирает - тот и поддерживает.